# How to embed a base64 data into Laravel 6 email

Tags: php, laravel

I'm string to embed an image raw data into any email client using [Laravel 6](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#inline-attachments) Embedding Raw Data Attachments.

In my test.blade.php:

```php
<body>
    Here is an image from raw data:

    <img src="{{ $message->embedData($data, $name) }}">
</body>
```

```php
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.test')
                    ->with([
                        'data' => 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA.....',
                        'name' => 'foobar',
                       ]);
    }
```

I've created a route to view the email and the image wont show. If I do:

```php
[...]
<img src="{{ $data }}">
```

The image shows (in browser) but not in the email. Fair enough. How to get `$message->embedData($data, $name)` to work? Am I missing something from the docs?

Comment: Maybe `$message->embed('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA')` could also work.

Comment: @RolandStarke Oh man, only if you had replied earlier! That also worked, cool!

Answer (score 4):

I had to analysed [my post](https://medium.com/@mayneweb/upload-a-base64-image-data-from-nodejs-to-aws-s3-bucket-6c1bd945420f) about image upload and see what I did there. So the php version is:

```php
        $data = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA.....";
        $img = preg_replace('/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/', '', $data);
        $type = explode(';', $data)[0];
        $type = explode('/', $type)[1];
        $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
        $data = base64_decode($img);
        return $this->view('emails.test')
                    ->with([
                        'name' => 'foobar',
                        'type' => $type, // png, jpg etc
                        'base64Data' => $data
        ]);
```

Then in the blade template:

```php
<img src="{{ $message->embedData($base64Data, $name . '.' . $type) }}">
```

Hope this helps others who are looking.